# VLC Playing Embedded in MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to embed **VLC video player** into one of my Access forms so that users can select a video they have uploaded and play it within Access.

I found code from this website:
http://workingwithaccess2007.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/vb-embedding-video-player-using-vlc.html

But the code which was given doesn't work now. It could be something to do with new updates in VLC which has caused the code to not work.

```
Dim player As VLCPlugin2
Set player = VLC.Object

Dim strURL As String

strURL = "C:\temp\1.mwv"

player.playlist.Add strURL
player.playlist.play
```

My main issue is that I tried embedding **Windows Media Player** initially and it caused Access to continuously crash which is why I'm seeking an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used this before, so can't profess to be an expert, but I managed to get the player running when the form was opened.

Make sure you've got a reference set to the VLC plugin (Alt + F11 > Tools > References):

[image]

In design view on your form, go to the controls section and expand it so you can get at the Active X controls:

[image]

Select the v2 VLC control:

[image]

Select your form by putting a dot in the top-left:

[image]

Using an event to trigger playback (I used the `Form_Current` event) put the code you used, but note 2 changes which I have commented:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Dim player As VLCPlugin2
    Set player = Me.VLCPlugin22.Object ' <-- this should reference the VLC control you put on your form by name

    Dim strURL As String

    strURL = "File:///D:\videos\music\Radiohead - In Rainbows From The Basement [Live].avi" ' <-- this should start with File:///

    player.playlist.Add strURL
    player.playlist.play

End Sub
```

Then it should work... it does for me anyway :)

Comment: Great!  how do I clear the playlist each time? it only adds to the playlist but this does work :)

Comment: I can't get access to the playlist when it's embedded in Access form to test... how do you access playlist?