# Play movie using VLC from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an excel vba program/macro that will start a movie stored locally on my hard-drive in vlc player using the vlc activex plug-in (axvlc.dll).  I'm able to register vlc so it appears in my Project References.  I'm also able to see AXVLC in the "Object Browser".  But I can't get any code to work that doesn't give "Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create."  I'm using Excel 2016 and VBA 7.1.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
   Dim myVlC As Object
   Set myVlC = CreateObject("AXVLC.VLCPlugin2")
   myVlC.Visible = True
   myVlC.playlist.Add ("test.mkv")
   myVlC.playlist.Play
End Sub
```

I tried to follow the conversation here...  [Using VLC player activex within excel vba as a registration-free COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300607/using-vlc-player-activex-within-excel-vba-as-a-registration-free-com)
and here...
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/baec16d1-e85c-4be9-8751-966bef527756/vlc-player-and-excel-visual-basic-editor?forum=isvvba
with no success.

I've created a lot of simple macros, but never anything using ActiveX, or anything really this object oriented before.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: after you registered it, did you add it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that means - "did you add it?".  When I click Tools->References I see VideoLAN VLC ActiveX Plug-in in my list.  Is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: Oh, I did check the box!  If that's what you mean.

Comment: In that link someone said if you're using late-binding you should be using `VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2` instead of `AXVLC.VLCPlugin2`, but they also say that you can't use late-binding at all with this plugin (aka `CreateObject()`), so I'm not sure what the right answer here is.

Comment: aha - it just came to me where I had seen working code for VLC+VBA...  It was *my* post (lol), over on AWF.  **[Does this help](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showpost.php?p=1537834&postcount=2)** at all?  The post was re: Access but should be pretty close.  (Ha, funny reading stuff from "past me", referring to *"The"* StackOverflow [Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003530/vlc-playing-embedded-in-ms-access-2013); that very post could possibly be what got me started on *this* site.)

Comment: I tried VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2 - I get "user defined type not defined".

Comment: Rats.  I wish your post helped... but still nothing.  I get the error creating the object...   Set myVlC = New AXVLC.VLCPlugin2

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub Start_VLC()
'its working for me...
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String
    Dim strLoc As String

    strLoc = Worksheets("dbFilmes").Cells(2, 6).Value 'film location
    strProgramName = "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" 'vlc location
    strArgument = strLoc 'film location

    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```